# How do I create a DCG rule inverse to another in Prolog?

Tags: parsing, prolog, grammar, dcg

I am writing a Commodore BASIC interpreter in Prolog, and I am writing some DCGs to parse it. I have verified the DCGs below to work except for the `variable` one. My goal is this: for anything which isn't a boolean, integer, float, or a string, it's a variable. However, anything that I give it via `phrase` just results in `no`.

```
bool --> [true].
bool --> [false].
integer --> [1]. % how to match nums?
float --> [0.1].
string --> [Str], {atom_chars(Str, ['"' | Chars]), last(Chars, '"')}.
literal --> bool; integer; float; string.

variable --> \+ literal.
```

I ran a stack trace like this (with `gprolog`)

```
main :- trace, phrase(variable, [bar]).
```

Looking at this, I cannot figure out why `variable` fails, given that it fails for each case in `literal`. I'm guessing that the error is pretty simple, but I'm still stumped, so does anyone who's good at Prolog have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
| ?- main.
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)
      1    1  Call: phrase(variable,[bar]) ? 
      2    2  Call: variable([bar],_321) ? 
      3    3  Call: \+literal([bar],_348) ? 
      4    4  Call: literal([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Call: bool([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Fail: bool([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Call: integer([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Fail: integer([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Call: float([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Fail: float([bar],_348) ? 
      5    5  Call: string([bar],_348) ? 
      6    6  Call: atom_chars(bar,['"'|_418]) ? 
      6    6  Fail: atom_chars(bar,['"'|_418]) ? 
      5    5  Fail: string([bar],_348) ? 
      4    4  Fail: literal([bar],_348) ? 
      3    3  Exit: \+literal([bar],_348) ? 
      2    2  Exit: variable([bar],[bar]) ? 
      1    1  Fail: phrase(variable,[bar]) ? 

(2 ms) no
{trace}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on the other answer, the key problem is that a DCG rule like `\+ literal` does not consume items from the input. It only *checks* that the next item, if any, is not a `literal`.

To actually consume an item, you need to use a list goal, similarly to how you use a goal `[1]` to consume a `1` element. So:

```
variable -->
    \+ literal,  % if there is a next element, it's not a literal
    [_Variable]. % consume this next element, which is a variable
```

For example:

```
?- phrase(variable, [bar]).
true.

?- phrase((integer, variable, float), [I, bar, F]).
I = 1,
F = 0.1.
```

Having that singleton variable `_Variable` is a bit strange -- when you parse like this, you lose the name of the variable. When your parser is expanded a bit, you will want to use arguments to your DCG rules to communicate information out of the rules:

```
variable(Variable) -->
    \+ literal,  
    [Variable].
```

For example:

```
?- phrase((integer, variable(Var1), float, variable(Var2)), [I, bar, F, foo]).
Var1 = bar,
Var2 = foo,
I = 1,
F = 0.1.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can detect a string of integers like this (I've added an argument to collect the digits):

```
integer([H|T]) --> digit(H), integer(T).
integer([]) -->  [].
digit(0) --> "0".
digit(1) --> "1".
    ...
digit(9) --> "9".
```

As for `variable` -- it needs to consume text, so you'd want something similar to `integer` above, but change `digit(H)` to something that recognizes a character that's part of a "variable".

If you want further clues (although sometimes using slightly advanced tricks): https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=basics and the code is here: https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/master/library/dcg/basics.pl