# Properly matching a set of tokens against my BASIC grammar

Tags: parsing, prolog, grammar, dcg, unification

I am working on writing a BASIC interpreter in Prolog. DCGs are a little tricky, which is why I am having trouble here today.

Here is my grammar.

```
bool --> [true].
bool --> [false].

is_num_char(AD) :- AD = '.'; (atom_codes(AD, [D]), D >= 48, D =< 57).
number --> [].
number --> is_num_char, number.

quotes_on_atom(S) :- atom_chars(S, ['"' | C]), last(C, '"').
string --> quotes_on_atom.

literal --> bool; number; string.
variable --> \+ literal.

assignment --> string, ['='], expr.

equal --> expr, ['=='], expr.
not_equal --> expr, ['!='], expr.

if --> [if], expr, [then], expr.

for_decl --> [for], assignment, [to], number, [step], number.
for_next --> [next], integer.

expr --> literal; variable; assignment;
        equal; not_equal; if; for_decl; for_next.
```

Here is my `main` goal:

```
main :-
    % expected: [for, [i, '=', 0], to, '5', step, '1']
    trace, phrase(expr, [for, i, '=', '0', to, '5', step, '1']).
```

Here is the error I get:
`uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,is_num_char/2),number/0)`.

A stack trace revealed this:

```
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)
      1    1  Call: phrase(expr,[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      2    2  Call: expr([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      3    3  Call: literal([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      4    4  Call: bool([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      4    4  Fail: bool([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      4    4  Call: number([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      4    4  Exit: number([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      3    3  Exit: literal([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      2    2  Exit: expr([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      2    2  Redo: expr([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      3    3  Redo: literal([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      4    4  Redo: number([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
      5    5  Call: is_num_char([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_446) ? 
      5    5  Exception: is_num_char([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_459) ? 
      4    4  Exception: number([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      3    3  Exception: literal([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      2    2  Exception: expr([for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1'],_335) ? 
      1    1  Exception: phrase(expr,[for,i,=,'0',to,'5',step,'1']) ? 
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,is_num_char/2),number/0)
{trace}
```

It seems that `is_num_char` is being passed the whole list of tokens, along with something else. I do not understand why this is happening, given that the `number` rule accepts only one argument. Additionally, it's odd that the token list unifies with `number` to begin with. It should be unified with `for_decl` instead. If you are knowledgeable about Prolog DCGs please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: is_num_char is a procedure with arity 1 (not a DCG rule), whereas the call from the DCG rule number//0 will call is_num_char with arity 2

Comment: @gusbro Why do DCG rules need an arity of two?

Comment: Check out the documentation and referenced pages from [SWI manual](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG). Each DCG rule has two implicit extra arguments to maintain the difference list.

Comment: There are a few other problems with your grammar. For start, it only tries to parse but you are not building a parsing tree. This may or may not be what you want. You also get into a loop between expr and equal/not_equal as each rule has a nil transition that goes to the other without consuming input

Comment: @gusbro I was thinking that I would start by just doing one current grammar and then expanding it to build a parse tree. What do you mean by each rule for equal and not equal having a nil transition? Sorry, I'm just really new to parsing in general.

Comment: By getting in a loop with nil transitions I mean that you go from the first rule to the second without consuming any input (nil transition) and then from the second rule you go again to the first one without consuming any input too. So you get into a loop. `expr --> equal` and then `equal --> expr, ....`

Comment: @gusbro I guess that that makes sense. My remaining question then is how to consume input tokens.

Comment: You can rewrite your rules so as to ensure at least one token is consumed prior to "closing the loop".

Comment: *"how to consume input tokens"* As in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486093/how-do-i-create-a-dcg-rule-inverse-to-another-in-prolog, the way to consume tokens is with `[Token]`. Always. This is the only way. For your `is_num_char` problem, you can replace `number --> is_num_char, number.` with `number --> [Char], { is_num_char(Char) }, number.`. Because `is_num_char` is a "normal" non-DCG predicate, you need to wrap it in `{ }` when calling it from a DCG rule.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Thank you, that makes sense.